# My computer doesn't log back in after suspend

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, suspend

I am running Xubuntu Xenial, kernel 4.4.25-040425-generic. The problem I had originally on the 4.4.0-53-generic kernel, after some research I come to understand that the problem was common with the 4.4.0 kernel and if I switch to 4.4.25 it would be fixed. That was not the case. Send help.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't log back in after suspend" ? Don't you get GUI at all, or do you just have to enter password to get back in ?

Comment: I do get the GUI, I can get to the greeter and login. However, after I login the screen goes black with a blinking underscore at the top left corner. Never to return.